# 3 Widget Positions: Image Top and Image Plus Text full width at bottom

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm having trouble positioning the following on a page:

- Image at top
- Image + Text touching bottom in that order

Here is the code but I just can't pull it all together:

```
Widget body = Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                logo,
                Container(child: Expanded(child: rotator)),
                Container(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  height: 25,
                  child: Text("here",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.teal, fontSize: 20)),
                )
              ]),
        ));
```

Image depicting what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not specific to me, but maybe this is what you are trying to achieve? `Flexible` might help solve your problem and this can help you with the responsiveness of your app too

```
Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
      child: Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(flex: 2, child: Container(color: Colors.red, width: double.infinity),),
            Spacer(),
            Flexible(flex: 3, child: Container(color: Colors.green, width: double.infinity)),
            Flexible(flex: 1, child: Container(color: Colors.blue, width: double.infinity))
               ]
            )
      )
```

[image]

Comment: I ended up using a solution like this.  Thanksl

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Widget body = Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
    child: Center(
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image1,
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image2,
                TextField(),
              ],
            ),
          ]),
    ));
```

Comment: You must be specific size of column Widget.

Comment: When you say specific size of column  widget, do you suggest adding a sizebox or something?  What you wrote works great  with the vertical layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```dart
final body = Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
  // No need to use the `Center` widget
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      logo,
      Spacer(), // Add this line
      rotator, // Use only the required image
      SizedBox(
        // If you are specifying only the size, `SizedBox` is better.
        width: double.maxFinite,
        height: 25,
        child: Text(
          "here",
          style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.teal, fontSize: 20),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```